# Wordpress admin-ajax.php 400 bad request

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, forms

I try tu run wp form with ajax but console return
Wordpress admin-ajax.php 400 bad request.

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
    
    
            jQuery('#form_add_to_cart').on('submit', function () {
                
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
                    method: 'post',
                    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: $("#form_add_to_cart").serializeArray(),
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    fail: function (err) {
                        alert("There was an error: " + err);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
```

here is my functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_send_form', 'send_form'); // This is for authenticated users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_form', 'send_form'); // This is for unauthenticated users.

function send_form(){
    if (isset($_POST['send_form'])){
        echo'ok';
    }
    else{
        echo 'bad';
    }
}
```

and my form:

```
            <form name="form_add_to_cart" method="POST" class="form_product" id="form_add_to_cart" action="">

                        <input hidden="hidden" name="action" id="add_product_to_cart"
                               value="send_form">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
                               name="add_to_cart-<?php echo $product_id; ?>" id="add_to_cart"
                               value="Dodaj">
```

all form : https://pastebin.com/YJXTjGjJ

WORKING:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {


            jQuery('#form_add_to_cart').on('submit', function () {

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
                    method: 'post',
                    data: $("#form_add_to_cart").serializeArray(),
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    fail: function (err) {
                        alert("There was an error: " + err);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: "i have multiple forms for each product in my page, but ajax working only for first form" -you've used '#form_add_to_cart' as a selector. That potentially only selects a single element with id=form_add_to_cart: ids ought to be unique on the page.

Comment: Ok I change selector from ID to class, now click working, but still error 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [full form code](https://pastebin.com/raw/YJXTjGjJ) does contain a hidden input named `action` with the value `send_form`.

However, you're not sending it correctly, because of the the `contentType` part in your JS script, which submits the form data as a JSON payload, but note that the old `admin-ajax.php` endpoint doesn't support JSON payload, hence `$_REQUEST['action']` would be empty unless if you added it to the URL query string, and therefore WordPress won't know what the AJAX action is. So just remove the following from your JS code and the error would be gone:

```js
contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // remove this
```

Additionally, your form doesn't have an input named `send_form`, so in your `send_form()` function, this will fail: `if (isset($_POST['send_form']))`. So you should add the input to your form or change the `if` condition.

Also, you should call `wp_die()` at the end in your function to exit the page and prevent WordPress from printing a `0` (zero).

Comment: Thank you that's working.
Now i can't display passed data to my function.
I run send_form(); on the same page when I Call ajax, and nothing display.

Comment: Your function as it stands now doesn't display any of the submitted data, but it would actually display either "ok" or "bad". And to retrieve the submitted data, just use the `$_POST['input name']` format, e.g. `$_POST['quantity']`. Also, try `var_dump( $_POST );` at the top in the function and you'd see a list of the submitted form data. But your original question has already been answered, so if you have another question, you can ask in another post. However, keep in mind, generic PHP questions are off-topic on this stack and should be asked on Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: Also, please undo your question's edit, i.e. roll back to the previous/original version. If you wanted to add new code, append it at the bottom and not modifying the part I told you to remove :)

Comment: It return me data like:

array(2) { ["action"]=> string(9) "send_form" ["formData"]=> array(9) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "quantity" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(7) "do_wash" ["value"]=> string(2) "on" } [2]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(10) "product_id" ["value"]=> string(2) "12" } [3]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(13) "product_price" ["value"]=> string(3) "0.5" } [4]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(26) "product_person_to_bringing" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [5]=> array(2)  } } }

Comment: Now it return:
array(2) { ["action"]=> string(9) "send_form" ["formData"]=> string(178) "quantity=1&do_wash=on&product_id=12&product_price=0.5&product_person_to_bringing=0&product_wash_price=0.2&product_bringing_price=0.4&product_calculate_bringing=0&action=send_form" } id_produktu0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129914/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-ncti).

Answer (score 2):

In the data property you need to pass the action to be called with the rest of your data.
Based on you ajax action you action should be `send_form`

```js
data: {
    action: 'send_form',
    formData: $("#form_add_to_cart").serialize()
}
```

Now in your php callback function you can do `print_r($_POST)` to see what the post request contains.

Comment: Unfortunately the same error.

Comment: @NCTI After the ajax request, can you go into network -> fetch/xhr -> find the request and check the response, what does it say?

Comment: And i have multiple forms for each product in my page, but ajax working only for first form.

Comment: I see 0 in network -> fetch/xhr ->response

Comment: @NCTI seems like your url is incorrect, make sure you passed the correct url, if you are using `url: 'https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'` im 100% sure it will not work, change it to your domain

Comment: *And i have multiple forms for each product in my page, but ajax working only for first form.*, the submit works for every form with that id but the data being passed is taken from the first form with that id. Instead of `$("#form_add_to_cart").serialize(),` do `$(this).serialize(),`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129913/discussion-between-ncti-and-buttered-toast).

Comment: when I received data in php try using json_decode($data) and it retunr me nothing.